# Find field absolute position and dimension by acrokey

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Given an acrokey, is it possible to find the absolute position and dimension of that particular field (getLeft, getTop, getWidth, getHeight) ?

And is the viceversa possible - if I know the position, can I get the acrokey of the field?

Answer (score 3):

**First part of your question:**

Suppose that you have an `AcroFields` instance (`form`), either retrieved from a `PdfReader` (read only) or a `PdfStamper` instance, then you can get the field position of the first widget that corresponds with a specific field `name` like this:

```
Rectangle rectangle = form.getFieldPositions(name).get(0).position;
```

Note that one field can correspond with multiple widgets. For instance, to get the second widget, you need:

```
Rectangle rectangle = form.getFieldPositions(name).get(1).position;
```

Of course: you probably also want to know the page number:

```
int page = form.getFieldPositions(name).get(0).page;
```

**Second part of your question**

Fields correspond with widget annotations. If you know the page number of the widget annotation, you could get the page dictionary and inspect the entries of the `/Annots` array. You'll have to loop over the different annotations, inspecting each annotation's `/Rect` entry. Once you find a match, you need to crawl the content for the field that corresponds with the annotation. That's more work than can be provided in a code sample on this site.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
First part - Worked fine
Second Part - We have two exacts pdf (one for test, another for production). From the test pdf, I can get the acrofields for the signature. I need only three fields, and there are more than 70 forms. I will manually verify the test pdfs. Using the acrokeys we got from test pdfs, can we get the related acrokeys from the respective prod pdf?

Comment: *Using the acrokeys we got from test pdfs, can we get the related acrokeys from the respective prod pdf?* - How are they *related*?

Comment: same content, same field with different acrokeys.. We make our changes in test pdf. Once everything is done, the last test version will be used to create a prod pdf.

Comment: Just to be sure: when you say "acrokey", do you mean "field name"? Your comment doesn't clarify the question. "Once everything is done, the last test version will be used to create a prod PDF" is meaningless to a third party such as me or mkl or any other SO user as long as you don't explain the context of what you're trying to achieve.