# Pdf form fields position retrieval with Itext

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

With iTextSharp, I can retrieve all the form fields that are present in a PDF form.I'm using Adobe acrobat reader to edit the PDF, where I see, every field have a position attribute which denotes where the PDF field will reside in a form.

So my question is, can I read that value ?

For example if I have a form field Name in a PDF form, can I get the position value of this field, like left 0.5 inches, right 2.5 inches, top 2 inches, bottom 2 inches ?

Right now I'm retrieving the form fields with the below code :

```
string pdfTemplate = @"D:\abc.pdf";
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);

var fields = reader.AcroFields;

int ffRadio = 1 << 15;      //Per spec, 16th bit is radio button
int ffPushbutton = 1 << 16; //17th bit is push button
int ff;

//Loop through each field
foreach (var f in fields.Fields)
{
    String type = "";
    String name = f.Key.ToString();
    String value = fields.GetField(f.Key);

    //Get the widgets for the field (note, this could return more than 1, this should be checked)
    PdfDictionary w = f.Value.GetWidget(0);

    //See if it is a button-like object (/Ft == /Btn)
    if (!w.Contains(PdfName.FT) || !w.Get(PdfName.FT).Equals(PdfName.BTN))
    {
        type = "T";
    }
    else
    {
        //Get the optional field flags, if they don't exist then just use zero
        ff = (w.Contains(PdfName.FF) ? w.GetAsNumber(PdfName.FF).IntValue : 0);

        if ((ff & ffRadio) == ffRadio)
        {
            //Is Radio
            type = "R";
        }
        else if (((ff & ffRadio) != ffRadio) && ((ff & ffPushbutton) != ffPushbutton))
        {
            //Is Checkbox
            type = "C";
        }
        else
        {
            //Regular button
            type = "B";
        }
    }

    //MessageBox.Show(type + "=>" + name + "=>" + value);
    FormFields fld = new FormFields(name, type, value, "inputfield" +form_fields.Count);

    form_fields.Add(fld);

    if (type.Equals("T"))
        addContent(form_fields.Count);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was about to close this question as a duplicate of [Find field absolute position and dimension by acrokey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23104809/find-field-absolute-position-and-dimension-by-acrokey) but that's a Java answer, and although most developers have no problem converting the Java to C#, it may be helpful for some developers to get the C# answer.

Fields in a PDF are visualized using widget annotations. One field can correspond with different of those annotations. For instance, you could have a field named `name` that is visualized on every page. In this case, the value of this field would be shown on every page.

There's a `GetFieldPositions()` method that returns a list of multiple positions, one for every widget annotations.

This is some code I copied from the answer to the question [iTextSharp GetFieldPositions to SetSimpleColumn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096093/itextsharp-getfieldpositions-to-setsimplecolumn)

```
IList<AcroFields.FieldPosition> fieldPositions = fields.GetFieldPositions("fieldNameInThePDF");
if (fieldPositions == null || fieldPositions.Count <= 0) throw new ApplicationException("Error locating field");
AcroFields.FieldPosition fieldPosition = fieldPositions[0];
left = fieldPosition.position.Left;
right = fieldPosition.position.Right;
top = fieldPosition.position.Top;
bottom = fieldPosition.position.Bottom;
```

If one field corresponds with one widget annotation, then `left`, `right`, `top`, and `bottom` will give you the left, right, top and bottom coordinate of the field. The width of the field can be calculated like this: `right - left`; the height like this: `top - bottom`. These values are expressed in *user units*. By default there are 72 user units in one inch.

If your document contains more than one page, then `fieldPosition.page` will give you the page number where you'll find the field.

All of this is documented on http://developers.itextpdf.com/